# Autocad Object Snaps Near macro

Tags: object, macros, autocad

I have this macro to  increment numbers on each click. I would like it to set to object snap Near before i click so it will just snap the number to the nearest thing i click.

```
*^C^C_text;\;$M=$(+,$(getvar,USERI1),1);setvar;USERI1;$M=$(+,$(getvar,USERI1),1);
```

Also is there anyway to change this so the text is rotated 90deg? As a separate macro.

Answer (score 0):

near osnap:-
Code:

```
*^C^C_text;NEAR;\;$M=$(+,$(getvar,USERI1),1);setvar;USERI1;$M=$(+,$(getvar,USERI1),1);
```

For the 90 deg option;-
Code:

```
*^C^C_text;\90;$M=$(+,$(getvar,USERI1),1);setvar;USERI1;$M=$(+,$(getvar,USERI1),1);
```

Comment: You need an underscore prefix (i.e. _NEAR) to remain language neutral.